# Borrar un Objeto como clave en Un Map Java

Tags: java

Como se Borra un objecto que se guarda como clave en una lista Map, pasándola por parámetros y buscándola dentro del Map y comprobando si existe y a continuación borrarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te ayude el siguiente código:

```
    HashMap<Object,String> map = new HashMap<Object, String>();

    private void eliminarObjeto(Object objeto){
        if(map.containsKey(objeto)){
            map.remove(objeto);
        }
    }
```

Saludos :)

Comment: ¿No es necesario hacer un _override_ de getHashCode() y toEquals() para que funcione correctamente eso?

Comment: No porque es una **HashMap**, esta es una abstracción de Map.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que no es necesario? Cuando haces _map.containsKey(objeto)_, internamente, itera la colección y compara el objeto usando el _getHashCode()_ y el _toEquals()_.

Comment: Si estoy seguro, te dejo un código si quieres comprobarlo:
`import java.util.HashMap;
public class HelloWorld {
    static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        map.put("uno","uno");
        map.put("dos","uno");
        eliminarObjeto("dos");
        System.out.println("size: "+map.size());
    }
    private static void eliminarObjeto(String objeto){
        if(map.containsKey(objeto)){
            map.remove(objeto);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Los tipos nativos (como el String que usas) tienen implementado, de fabrica, los métodos _getHashCode()_ y _toEquals()_. Los _POJOs_ usan la implementación de Object, la cual no es valida para el _negocio_ del objeto, ya que comparar un _object_ no es lo mismo que un _POJO_.

Comment: Claro, entiendo tu punto, pero eso es cuando usas POJO. Tu te tienes que encargar de sobrecargar los métodos que mencionas o en todo caso le dices que quieres esos métodos a la herramienta que te los genera. En este caso es más sencillo porque son Objects de java.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Por la Respuesta me ha servido de gran ayuda, pero a la hora de borrar el objecto en concreto, me borra toda la lista Map, y le he pasado el objecto en concreto, ¿sabes de que podría ser?

Comment: Puede que estés pasando el mismo objeto en cada llave del map, te aconsejo que no uses objetos como llaves, es mejor usar un id(String) o algo que lo identifique como único. Saludos